# Java asynchronous method call / background processing

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

[JAVA] I am having a use case and I am wondering the best way to approach it. I have a current implementation in the following manner (pseudo-code), but it takes a lot of time to process:

```
Func (File) // Called when a file is uploaded
{

    1.doSomething()
    2.Result=LongRunningTask(File)
    3.WriteToFS(Result)

}
```

Now I want to take out 2, & 3 and execute them in background and return quickly. If multiple calls are made to Func() ,  it should Queue and execute them one by one so the writing to FS is not affected. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an ExecutorService to launch tasks in the background.  The `submit` method in `ExecutorService` takes in a `Callable<T>` and returns a `Future` object immediately.  You can use the `Future` object to query the progress of the operation (whether its completed or canceled or still running) and to get the result of the operation after it's finished.  You can manage how many concurrent background operations you allow by the size of the thread pool given to the `ExecutorService` (a thread pool of 1 would allow you to queue background operations in called order, as you requested, but you could increase that number and allow concurrent operations).

Check out http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/02/javautilconcurrentfuture-basics.html for a good example on how to use `ExecutorService` and `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I have understood your question correctly. If your concern is how to execute 2 & 3 asynchronously, you can look into ExecutorService interface at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html
A good tutorial on executorService can be found at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html

Now, if you are looking at queuing up requests to the method, the easiest way is to synchronize it. It may not be a good solution from performance aspect but it is easier to implement.